# SWRevealViewController: Changing the height of front view

Tags: ios, xcode

i am using "SWRevealViewController" in xcode. i m getting sidebar in iPhone but i want to resize the height of front view when menu is open. how can i?

i am using this code:

```
_frontView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, bounds.size.height/6 , bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height/1.5);
```